# Compiling all the files in a folder using python shell on Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, python-2.5

To compile a python file from shell, one can type

```
python -O filename.py
```

In a situation where there are many files, this can be tasking. How can I use this command or any other command to compile all the .py files in a folder at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how Python is written in this regard,

```
python -O *.py
```

might suffice. Otherwise

```
for /f in %x in (*.py) do python -O "%x"
```